# how can i use mysql binlog functions from libmysqlclient

Tags: c++, mysql, c, shared-libraries, mysql-connector

I want to use `mysql_binlog_open` `mysql_binlog_fetch` `mysql_binlog_close` like https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/c-api-binary-log-interface-usage.html

I download libmysqlclient.so from https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-8.0/mysql-8.0.28-linux-glibc2.17-x86_64-minimal.tar.xz

when i link my program i got

```
g++ test.o -L./lib -lmysqlclient
./test.o: In function `test_binlog':
test.c:(.text+0x2c2): undefined reference to `mysql_binlog_open'
test.c:(.text+0x2f3): undefined reference to `mysql_binlog_fetch'
test.c:(.text+0x3e7): undefined reference to `mysql_binlog_close'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

in readelf the binlog functions is `FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT`

```
$readelf -a libmysqlclient.so|grep binlog
  2439: 000000000003aec0    39 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   12 mysql_binlog_close
  3340: 000000000003ae50   108 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   12 mysql_binlog_fetch
  3386: 000000000003abf0   596 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   12 mysql_binlog_open
```

other functions is `FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT`

```
  4586: 000000000003c970   321 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 mysql_close
  4714: 0000000000030280   351 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 mysql_stmt_close
```

how can i use the binlog functions

Comment: Have you tried using the full rather than the minimal download?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Using  https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-8.0/mysql-8.0.28-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64.tar.xz has the same problem